# How can I resolve an unexpected character error when trying to import selected data from a large JSON file?

Tags: import, json-format

I'm downloading this [datafile](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/Cornell-University/arxiv?resource=download) from kaggle.

I want to get all the IDs.

Normally for a JSON file I'd write

```
Import["./arxiv-metadata-oai-snapshot.json", {"Data", "id"}]
```

But I get the error

```
Import::jsonexpendofinput: Unexpected character found while looking for the end of input.
Import::jsonhintposandchar: An error occurred near character '"', at line 2:3
```

The only way I'd know to fix this is to import the ENTIRE file. It's massive. I really don't want to do that.

Comment: `https://jsonlint.com` gives good suggestions for fixing JSON strings. Just paste your file in there & check. Maybe paste by sections, especially the section you're having trouble with (JSON is a hierarchical format and you can extract subsections at any level).

Comment: That file has the extension `.json` but its contents don't appear to be a valid JSON.  Each *line* looks like valid JSON, but the entire file is not.  This is a good thing, because a 3.5GB JSON string sounds like a horrible idea

Comment: Any trick to import each line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Any trick to import each line?

The key here is to open the file as a stream rather than trying to import it at once.  Once you have it open as a stream use `ReadLine` to read in a single line at a time.  Then you can `ImportString` the line itself and get its `"id"` field.

Something like this would work

```
stream = OpenRead @ "arxiv-metadata-oai-snapshot.json";
(* use a dynamic array to capture the results incrementally *)
res = CreateDataStructure @ "DynamicArray";
Monitor[
    lineNumber = 0;
    While[(line = ReadLine @ stream) =!= EndOfFile,
        id = ImportString[line, "RawJSON"]["id"];
        res["Append", id];
        lineNumber++
    ],
    lineNumber
];
(* now convert the dynamic array into a list *)
res = Normal @ res;
```

Note I'm using `Monitor` so you can keep track of how far you are into the 2 million lines in the file.

You may find the above to be a little slow, because it has to import the entire JSON string for each line and grab the id field.  If I know that each line has what I want written *exactly* like `"id":"the_id_i_want"` then I could replace the

```
id = ImportString[....
```

line with

```
id = First[
  StringCases[line, 
   "\"id\":\"" ~~ Shortest[id__] ~~ "\"" :> id], $Failed]
```

and it goes much faster.